# I have a project in Java I am running that uses an external JAR file

Tags: java

I have a project in Java I am running that uses an external JAR file.

In Eclipse I added the JAR file to the class build path and everything working fine.

But my question is: how can I add it to my project after I created the executable JAR (myPtog.jar)
and I am running "ant" in cmd but the external jar file is not found?

This is my build.xml:

```
<project name="" default="dist" basedir=".">
    <description>
        Ant
    </description>

    <!-- Set global properties for this build. -->
    <property name="src" location="src"/>
    <property name="build" location="target"/>

    <target name="init">
        <tstamp/>
        <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init" description="compile the source ">
        <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="dist" depends="compile" description="generate the distribution">
        <jar jarfile="TPCServer.jar" basedir="${build}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Main1"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="clean" description="clean up">
        <delete dir="${build}"/>
        <delete dir="${dist}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: What does your script look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks for the reference... it's pretty cool.  I just suggest that if anyone uses this they be SURE to also release an autorun jar version as well for Linux and Mac users.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse, on Project Explorer view, right click your project, than `Export...` -> `Java` -> `Runnable JAR File`. This will re-package all your libs (jars) with your project. Watch out for license permission for re-packaging.

Comment: This will also allow you to create an ant build script when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set CLASSPATH appropriately to contain the path of the executable jar as well as the external jars.

Answer (score 0):

[Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) may do the trick for you.  It will auto-configure your project for the most part and give you a simple command line for building a target JAR.